# How to obatin a different interface from a COM object in PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, com, envdte

Using COM methods like `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE")` I can navigate the Visual Studio DTE object model fine. For instance from [DTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.debugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) object I can get [`Debugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), and then [`LocalProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debugger.localprocesses?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), and the the [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.process?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) object. But I need the derived [`Process2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.process2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface on it, to call [`Attach2("<my debug engine>")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.process2.attach2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).
I could not find a way to obtain the interface I want, a simple cast results in runtime error: `Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject#{5c5a0070-f396-4e37-a82a-1b767e272df9}" to type "EnvDTE80.Process2"`.

```
PS> $dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE")
PS> $p = $dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses | where {$_.ProcessID -eq 11212}
PS> $p


Name       : C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
ProcessID  : 11212
Programs   : System.__ComObject
DTE        : System.__ComObject
Parent     : System.__ComObject
Collection : System.__ComObject



PS> [EnvDTE80.Process2]$p2 = $p
Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject#{5c5a0070-f396-4e37-a82a-1b767e272df9}" to type "EnvDTE80.Process2".
At line:1 char:1
+ [EnvDTE80.Process2]$p2 = $p
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, at least not in a way that PowerShell will be able to remember when it comes to member binding.

PowerShell only ever operates based on runtime information.  Even if you cast it in C# first, if `QueryInterface` returns the same pointer for that interface then all PowerShell is going to see is the `IDispatch` it currently detects.  Even if the object you obtained was a strongly typed version from the primary interop assembly, PowerShell only sees concrete types (which there doesn't seem to be one for `Process2`).

As a workaround, you can use reflection:

```
[EnvDTE80.Process2].InvokeMember(
    'Attach2',
    [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,
    <# binder: #> $null,
    <# target: #> $process,
    <# args: #> @($myEngine))
```